# Image loading in Chrome and Firefox but not IE

Tags: html

A strange problem.

I have the following...

```
<img src="images/source.png" border="0"/>
```

The image loads in Chrome and Firefox but not IE!

I have tried renaming the image, changing the format of the image etc etc.

What could be causing this?

Comment: What version of IE? And what's with the `border` on the img? That's deprecated.

Comment: Tested in Internet Explorer 10, it's working.

Comment: Using the img in a hyperlink so it would be <a href="#"><img src="images/source.png" border="0"/></a>

Comment: Still working, you might want to upgrade. Or try posting your code, maybe something else is interacting.

Comment: Can you acces yoursite/images/source.png?

Answer (score 1):

Its very late to answer this, but someone might need a solution for this

> Issue may be caused if your images are saved with a CMYK color profile
>   instead of an RGB color profile. Microsoft Internet Explorer 8.0
>   dropped support for jpeg images saved as CMYK and now only supports
>   images saved in RGB mode.

or

> Issue can be very weird like someone renaming .jpg image to .gif or
>   vice-verse and trying to view it in IE

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to delete your IE cookies and to try to load your page again, because nothing with this code to effect it loading with IE!

Answer (score -1):

You should first check with IE developer tools as to why it isn't loading. Wrong path?

I'd also suggest adding a `./` to the beginning of your path to force the browser to understand it's a cwd relative path

```
<img src="./images/source.png" border="0"/>
```

Comment: Yes checked the path and it is correct. Tried /. but still no success.